# ORACLE transact UPDATE with order by

Tags: oracle11g, sql-update, sql-order-by

1. I need to update a table by using "order by". Because I am updating line |numbers by a group of   columns. But I have an parentheses error. The thing is that there is no parentheses error. I do not understand why my oracle transact sql code is not functioning.

```
UPDATE SET_MYIG a set "LINEID" = (SELECT b."LINEID"
FROM SET_MYIG_UPDATE_LINEID b 
WHERE  a."Fil1"=b.Filler1
and a."Fil2"=b.Fil2 
and a."Fil3"=b.Fil3 and a."Fil4"=b.Fil4 
and a."Fil5"=b.Fil5 
order by b."LineID");
```

### `SET_MYIG_UPDATE_LINEID` initialised with `Rownum` and then I have to update the Table

> 2- Thank your very much for your responde. I will take your
> recommendations about the double quotes and order by. I understand that I cannot put order by in a subquery sending 1 line.
> I have changed my code by passing through  LOOP in order to
> UPDATE my table and ASC. I do not have a syntax error. The code is
> executing well but the update is not working. My column stays "null".
> I think I dont have Loop error.
>
> BEGIN DECLARE     Vmaxnum  number;     Vcounter  number;    Vexec
> varchar(1000);    BEGIN
>
> ```
>   SELECT MAX(MyLine) into Vmaxnum  FROM SET_MYIG_UPDATE_LINEID;
>
>   FOR Vcounter in 1..Vmaxnum LOOP
>
>      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (Vcounter);
>      UPDATE SET_MYIG a set "LINEID" = (SELECT b.MyLine
>      FROM SET_MYIG_UPDATE_LINEID b 
>      WHERE  a."Fil1"=b.Filler1
>      and a."Fil2"=b.Fil2 
>      and a."Fil3"=b.Fil3 
>      and a."Fil4"=b.Fil4 
>      and a."Fil5"=b.Fil5 
>      and b.MyLine = Vcounter  );
>   END LOOP;  
>   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (Vcounter);    END;  END;
> ```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected contents of the tables after the `UPDATE` statement. Your code is syntactically invalid as you need to remove the `ORDER BY` but beyond telling you what is wrong it is difficult (impossible?) to tell you what would be a correct answer because you have not told us what your data is or what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to update a table by using "order by". But I have an parentheses error. The thing is that there is no parentheses error.

There is an error, it is a syntax error that the SQL engine forbids the use of an `ORDER BY` clause in a sub-query that Oracle expected to return a single row containing a scalar value because, when you are returning a single row then `ORDER BY` is pointless.

Because the `ORDER BY` clause is forbidden as invalid syntax then the SQL engine expects the sub-query to end at `and a."Fil5"=b.Fil5` and the parenthesis that closes the sub-query to immediately follow and when it doesn't (and instead something invalid, such as `ORDER BY`, follows) then the exception is raised that a parenthesis was expected but was not present. This may seem confusing but there is logic to the error message if you know why it was raised; if you don't know why it was raised then the error message is just confusing.

If your sub-query does return a single value then just remove the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
UPDATE SET_MYIG a
set LINEID = ( SELECT b.LINEID
               FROM   SET_MYIG_UPDATE_LINEID b 
               WHERE  a."Fil1"=b.Filler1
               and    a."Fil2"=b.Fil2 
               and    a."Fil3"=b.Fil3
               and    a."Fil4"=b.Fil4 
               and    a."Fil5"=b.Fil5 
             );
```

If your query does not return a single row then fix your query so that it does return a single row. For example, either by:

1. Using `ROWNUM`:

   ```sql
   UPDATE SET_MYIG a
   set LINEID = ( SELECT b.LINEID
                  FROM   SET_MYIG_UPDATE_LINEID b 
                  WHERE  a."Fil1"=b.Filler1
                  and    a."Fil2"=b.Fil2 
                  and    a."Fil3"=b.Fil3
                  and    a."Fil4"=b.Fil4 
                  and    a."Fil5"=b.Fil5 
                  AND    ROWNUM = 1
                );
   ```
2. Aggregating, for example, using `MAX`:

   ```sql
   UPDATE SET_MYIG a
   set LINEID = ( SELECT MAX(b.LINEID)
                  FROM   SET_MYIG_UPDATE_LINEID b 
                  WHERE  a."Fil1"=b.Filler1
                  and    a."Fil2"=b.Fil2 
                  and    a."Fil3"=b.Fil3
                  and    a."Fil4"=b.Fil4 
                  and    a."Fil5"=b.Fil5 
                  AND    ROWNUM = 1
                );
   ```

*Note: Using quoted identifiers is considered bad practice as you then have to always use quoted identifiers for that identifier and always use the correct case. In your query, you `SELECT b."LINEID"` and then `ORDER BY b."LineID"` and `"LINEID"` and `"LineID"` are **NOT** the same columns because they use quoted identifiers and have different case; this is probably an error on your part, and you only have a single column, but if you really do have two columns in the same table with the same name only different cases then **STOP** and fix your identifiers so that you do not need to use quoted identifiers and so that the columns can have different values (not just different cases).*